# Trigger Topbar buttons in test

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to test navigation events on a screen using `react-native-testing-library`.

I'm listening to the events globally using `Navigation.events().registerNavigationButtonPressedListener` with the following hook inside my Functional component:

```
const useTopBarBtnPress = function (
    componentId: string,
    onTopBtnPressed: OnTopBtnPressed) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const topBtnListener = Navigation.events().registerNavigationButtonPressedListener((event) => {
            if (event.componentId === componentId)
                onTopBtnPressed(event, BtnIds)
        })
        return () => topBtnListener.remove()
    }, [onTopBtnPressed])
}
```

Is it possible to simulate a topBar button for the test ? I guess using the testID but I can't find it in the doc.
Or do I need to mock `registerNavigationButtonPressedListener` ? Or use Detox ?

Also, is there a way to test the layout ? (eg. Icon color)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to actually mock TopBar buttons to test `navigationButtonPressed`. Simply invoke `navigationButtonPressed` yourself with the correct `NavigationButtonPressedEvent` parameter simulating a button press.

Comment: How can I do if I use `Navigation.events().registerNavigationButtonPressedListener` instead to invoke an event (edited my question accordingly) ?